# Sending json to asp.net view for creating chart.js programmatically

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, chart.js

I have an issue because I want to create chart.js programmatically from code behind asp.net (c# webforms). I have no idea if I am doing it well. When I send my json to the view, I receive an error in the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_meta' of null
    at t.getDatasetMeta (Chart.bundle.min.js:10)
    at t.<anonymous> (Chart.bundle.min.js:10)
    at Object.each (Chart.bundle.min.js:10)
    at t.buildOrUpdateControllers ( (...)
```

Here is my code :

```
var chart = new Chart
        {
            type = "pie",
            data = new ChartData
            {
                labels = new ChartLabels
                {
                    labels = new string[3] {"Open", "Close", "Nothing"}
                },
                datasets = new ChartDatasets
                {
                    data = new int[3] {20, 10, 3},
                    backgroundColor = new string[3] {"#ccf9d6", "#ccf9d6", "#ccf9d6"},
                    borderWidth = 1
                }
            }
        };
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(chart);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                                            "ServerControlScript", "addChart("+ json +");", true);
```

and my view function that creates chart.js

```
function addChart(data) {
                         var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
                         var myChart = new Chart(ctx, data)
                     }
```

Do you have any tips?

Comment: from where are you calling your addChart function

Comment: from code behind like you can see. Meaby I dont understand your question

Comment: what code ends up on your page?

Comment: View code is last and js function `addChart` called from scriptManager should be last. But I dont really know what do you have mean, if you are asking about function that call js script from code behind `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` in documentation it is said : _page's client onload event is raised. Startup script blocks are located at the bottom of the rendered ASP.NET page just before the </form> tag_

Comment: I think before creating chart object on last second line you need to deserialize your data

Comment: so before `var myChart = new Chart(ctx, data)` i need to deserialize `data` ? could you give me any example for this?

Comment: var deserialisedData = JSON.parse(data)